# I ran 'composer update' and it brought the website down. How to fix?

Tags: error, composer-update

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto
13 Amasty extensions
```

Someone recommended for me to run:

composer update

I have done this and now the front end does not load and shows the following Error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_DataExporter schema: current version - none, required version - 42.0.1
Magento_DataExporter data: current version - none, required version - 42.0.1
Magento_ServicesConnector schema: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Magento_ServicesConnector data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Magento_QueryXml schema: current version - none, required version - 42.0.0
Magento_QueryXml data: current version - none, required version - 42.0.0
Magento_ServicesId schema: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Magento_ServicesId data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Amasty_CheckoutCore schema: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Amasty_CheckoutCore data: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Magecomp_Smspro schema: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9
Magecomp_Smspro data: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_DataExporter schema: current version - none, required version - 42.0.1
Magento_DataExporter data: current version - none, required version - 42.0.1
Magento_ServicesConnector schema: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Magento_ServicesConnector data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Magento_QueryXml schema: current version - none, required version - 42.0.0
Magento_QueryXml data: current version - none, required version - 42.0.0
Magento_ServicesId schema: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Magento_ServicesId data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Amasty_CheckoutCore schema: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Amasty_CheckoutCore data: current version - 1.0.0, required version - 1.1.0
Magecomp_Smspro schema: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9
Magecomp_Smspro data: current version - 1.0.7, required version - 1.0.9
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/amasty/aminvisiblecaptcha/Plugin/Framework/App/FrontControllerInterface/ValidateCaptcha.php:123]
#2 Amasty\InvisibleCaptcha\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface\ValidateCaptcha->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:151]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:71]
#4 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:151]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:169]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

**This is an EMERGENCY. How can I fix this?**

---

**Update:**
THIS IS NOW RESOLVED!

**The issue in my case was a corrupted payment module which Tu Van helped me remove and it fixed the issue.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, you should run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to upgrade database.

---

**Updated**
When @Allysin running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` it does not complete (stuck) but does not show any errors in the terminal (some servers do not throw errors when running this command). So I've used `strace` to debugging: `strace -s 99999 bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Then it show the error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\\Framework\\Setup\\Declaration\\Schema\\Declaration\\SchemaBuilder::processTable() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\Setup\\Declaration\\Schema\\Dto\\Table, bool returned in vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php:253
```

After debugging, I found that `vendor/magento/module-payment-services-saas-export` module has an issue: when running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, it try to build table `payment_services_order_status_data_production_submitted_hash`
but it has an issue.

`module-payment-services-saas-export` is included in Payment Services extension (`magento/payment-services`), since @Allysin doesn't need this extension anymore, removing it resolved the issue.
`bin/magento setup:upgrade` running as expected and the website was back.

Comment: I ran this about a thousand times and it still does not work - Tu Van - please help me, please!

Comment: Back to the chat, I'll help.

Comment: thank you Tu Van.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I am awarding you 100 bounty points as promised.

Comment: @Allysin, if it works please share your solution so other can take benefits

Comment: @Tu Van - Sorry - it says: "You may award your bounty worth 100 reputation in 23 hours." I will do this when 23 hours are up!

Comment: @Amitkumar solanki - we may have to ask Tu Van for details but as I stated in my updated note in my original post - the issue was with a corrupted payment module. Once this was removed, it worked as expected.

Comment: Allysin: glad to help, no worries!
@Amitkumarsolanki I've updated the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

PLease run the following commands,

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I ran both of these multiple times and the website is still down. Please help me - pretty please.

Comment: Okay,it seems composer update is not update the required packages to install, please try to run the composer install and do the magento setup commands